# Javascript change value on class

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the following html:

```
<a class="nsg-form--drop-down--label nsg-grad--light-grey nsg-form--drop-down exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown selectBox-dropdown" style="" title="" tabindex="0">
                                <span class="js-selectBox-label">SIZE </span>
                                <span class="js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option">&nbsp;</span>
                              </a>
```

I tried the following but nothing changes.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option").value = '(US 8)'

document.getElementsByClassName("js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option").click

document.getElementsByClassName("js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option").select
```

I for some reason cannot change the value. This is what it looks like when you physically change the value.

```
<a class="nsg-form--drop-down--label nsg-grad--light-grey nsg-form--drop-down exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown selectBox-dropdown" style="" title="" tabindex="0">
                                <span class="js-selectBox-label">SIZE </span>
                                <span class="js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option">(US 8)</span>
                              </a>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should better describe what you are expecting the result to be.

Comment: Which elements are you trying to target? Neither an a element nor a span element have value properties (IIRC) so you may want to use innerText instead.

Comment: @JackBashford, AH I will try innerText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a htmlcollection. You need to get the index to change the text in it.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option")[0].innerHTML = '(US 8)'
```

```html
<a class="nsg-form--drop-down--label nsg-grad--light-grey nsg-form--drop-down exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown selectBox-dropdown" style="" title="" tabindex="0">
  <span class="js-selectBox-label">SIZE </span>
  <span class="js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option">&nbsp;</span>
```

Alternatively you can also use `document.querySelector`. It is always going to target the first available element in the dom

```js
document.querySelector('.nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option')
  .innerHTML = '(US-8)'
```

```html
<a class="nsg-form--drop-down--label nsg-grad--light-grey nsg-form--drop-down exp-pdp-size-dropdown exp-pdp-dropdown two-column-dropdown selectBox-dropdown" style="" title="" tabindex="0">
  <span class="js-selectBox-label">SIZE </span>
  <span class="js-selectBox-value nsg-form--drop-down--selected-option">&nbsp;</span>
```